# i need a query displaying records mysql java

Tags: java, mysql

I've created table finance and set one column date,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newloanauto` (
  `customerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `loannumber` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `vechiclenumber` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `vechiclename` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `vechicledescription` text NOT NULL,
  `insuranceexdte` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `loanamount` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `setinterest` double NOT NULL,
  `noofdues` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `interestcost` double NOT NULL,
  `total` double NOT NULL,
  `documentcharges` double NOT NULL,
  **`dates` date NOT NULL,**
  PRIMARY KEY (`loannumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

(102, '1002', '6656', 'fhh', 'hgh', '1212', 246356, 56, 656, 656, 100, 56, **'2014-09-23')**,

i want to alert particular customers after one month.how can i get particular records from table .(30 days due time)

Comment: a simple `select` statement with the date set 30 days from your set date should do it. i.e `select * from newloanauto where date=2014-10-23` are you looking for that specific date or 30 days from any date?

Comment: Add some input/output examples of your query. What would you like to get for a particular date? I do not understand your question.

Comment: stored new customer loan details particular date.after one month i want to retrieve 30 days records from stored date to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from newloanauto where date=(now()+interval 30 day)`
which is for 30 days from current date. You can substitute `now()` for any date you seem fit.